# When is a 'day' for the Welkin Moon bonus?

Tags: genshin-impact

During one of the recent web events I was rewarded with a [Blessing of the Welkin Moon](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Blessing_of_the_Welkin_Moon).

This awards Primogems for each day that you login. However my days count has been going down by two despite logging into the game on my mobile device each morning.

I am logging in around 07:30 UTC each day, and just this morning my days were showing 24, when yesterday they were 26.

When does a 'day' change in Genshin Impact?

Comment: pretty sure that is just the lingering anger refuse of all the players who got the mora prize instead. Be happy, apparently some of the more daring ones who posted pictures of the prize on Hoyolab were struck by Eleazar...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The daily reset occurs at 4:00 AM - ***server time***.

Since there are three server zones, the exact time depends on the server you play on and your own time zone.

- Asia: GMT+8
- Europe: GMT+1
- America: GMT-5

Note: you can safely consider UTC and GTM times to be roughly equivalents.

Comment: Seems that the reset is correct and my ability to count is incorrect. My boon was 23 days left this morning. So I was mis-remembering the number it seems.

Answer (score 2):

If this works as the [daily check-in](https://act.hoyolab.com/ys/event/signin-sea-v3/index.html), and it should, it's UTC+8 (for the European server).

Comment: So that would make my daily login at 15:30 UTC, so I should be fine. I will make a note that tomorrow should be 23 days remaining and double check

Comment: Welkin does not follow the hoyolab daily checkin schedule.

Comment: This is incorrect. Daily check in resets at 00:00 each day. Welkin follows daily reset, which is 04:00 each day (server time). @DavidYell Redacted's answer is the correct one.